# Is finite additivity a property of the Lebesegue outer measure?

Tags: measure-theory

In the Lebesgue outer measure we have the following properties: the length of the empty set is $0$, monotonicity and countable subadditivity.

My question is, is it possible to use the above properties to show finite additivity?

I have no idea where to begin (or even if it's true) so any hints are definitely appreciated.

Comment: You cannot prove it because it is false.

Comment: Even for disjoint sets?

Comment: Look the answer below: the point is the domain of outer measure are power set, and at the same time there exist nonmeasurable sets..However, finite additivity is, by definition, for disjoint sets

Comment: @Daniel Yes, even for disjoint sets. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Lebesgue outer measure is in fact **not finitely additive**. This can be shown via the usual construction of a [**Vitali decomposition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) of $[0, 1)$ - we can partition $[0, 1)$ into countably many sets $V_i$ which have the same outer measure $\kappa$. By countable subadditivity (and the fact that $[0, 1)$ doesn't have measure zero), we have $\kappa>0$; but then $m^*([0, 1))=1<\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}m^*(V_i)=\infty$.

(Note that the $V_i$s are *disjoint* - that's implied by the word "partition".)

---

How do we get a Vitali decomposition in the first place? If you haven't seen this before, it's a neat argument! Consider the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $[0, 1)$ given by $$a\sim b\iff a-b\in\mathbb{Q}.$$ Let $V\subseteq[0, 1)$ be a *transversal* of this equivalence relation - that is, $V$ contains exactly one element of each equivalence class.

*Note that in order to get $V$ we need the axiom of choice. Indeed, without AC it is consistent that **every** set is measurable!*

Now, if you imagine wrapping $[0, 1)$ into a circle, the rational translates of $V$ partition $[0, 1)$! Formally, for $q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap [0, 1)$ let $V+q=\{v+q: v\in V\}$, and let $$V_q=\{v+q: v+q\in [0, 1)\}\cup\{v+q-1: v+q\in [1, 2)\}$$ be the "wrapped around" version of $V+q$. Then you can show that:

- The $V_q$s partition $[0, 1)$,
- $m^*(V_p)=m^*(V_q)$ for $p, q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap [0, 1)$ (this is basically translation-invariance of $m^*$), and
- $m^*(V_p)>0$ for every $p\in\mathbb{Q}\cap [0, 1)$ (this uses the facts that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, the countable union of measure-zero sets is measure-zero, and $[0, 1)$ is not measure zero).

This is, I believe, the historically first example of a non-measurable set. ([There are others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set).)

Comment: For extreme examples of non-additivity of Lebesgue outer measure, see [Is there a maximum to the amount of disjoint non-measurable subsets of the unit interval with full outer measure?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119646/is-there-a-maximum-to-the-amount-of-disjoint-non-measurable-subsets-of-the-unit).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I didn't know that - that's very neat!

Comment: A stronger fact was proved by Lusin: Every set of reals can be partitioned into two subsets of the same Lebesgue outer measure. Reference: N. Lusin, Sur la d´ecomposition des ensembles, C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris 198 (1934), 1671-74